# Need to get cumulative count distinct by periods (year,month)

Tags: sql, postgresql, cumulative-frequency

I already managed to obtain a cumulative distinct count by months but I can't get it when trying to do it by years. I tried partition function but I keep getting all kinds of errors, this is what I got so far. Could you give me some guidance, Im new at this.

[SQL Fiddle][1]

**PostgreSQL 9.3 Schema Setup**:

```
create table table2 (id serial, fecha_captura date, mn integer, VALUACION1 integer);

    insert into table2 (fecha_captura, mn, VALUACION1)
    values
    ('1996-02-01',2,12345),
    ('1996-02-01',2,12345),
    ('1996-02-01',2,12344),
    ('1996-02-01',2,12343),
    ('1996-03-01',3,12345),
    ('1996-03-01',3,12346),
    ('1996-03-01',3,12347),
    ('1996-03-01',3,12348),
    ('1996-04-01',4,12349),
    ('1996-04-01',4,12350),
    ('1996-04-01',4,12351),
    ('1996-04-01',4,12352),
    ('1997-03-01',4,12353),
    ('1997-03-01',4,12354),
    ('1997-03-01',4,12345),
    ('1997-03-01',4,12352),
    ('1997-04-01',4,12353),
    ('1997-04-01',4,12354),
    ('1997-04-01',4,12345),
    ('1997-04-01',4,12355);
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT Year1,mn,
   COUNT(DISTINCT(VALUACION1)) AS Val_Dist_Mes
  ,SUM(flag) AS Val_Dist_Mes_Nuevas
  ,SUM(SUM(flag)) 
   OVER (partition by Year1 ORDER BY mn,Year1
         ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) AS Val_Dist_Acum 
FROM
 (
   SELECT
      VALUACION1
     ,EXTRACT(MONTH FROM fecha_captura) AS mn
     ,EXTRACT(YEAR FROM fecha_captura) AS Year1
     ,CASE
         WHEN EXTRACT(MONTH FROM fecha_captura) 
              = MIN (EXTRACT(MONTH FROM fecha_captura))
              OVER (PARTITION BY VALUACION1) 
         THEN 1 
         ELSE 0 
      END AS flag
   FROM table2
   GROUP BY fecha_captura,VALUACION1
 ) AS dt
GROUP BY mn,Year1
```

**[Results][2]**:

```
| year1 | mn | val_dist_mes | val_dist_mes_nuevas | val_dist_acum |
|-------|----|--------------|---------------------|---------------|
|  1996 |  2 |            3 |                   3 |             3 |
|  1996 |  3 |            4 |                   3 |             6 |
|  1996 |  4 |            4 |                   3 |             9 |
|  1997 |  3 |            4 |                   3 |             3 |
|  1997 |  4 |            4 |                   1 |             4 |
```

---

**[EXPECTED RESULTS][2]**:

```
| year1 | mn | val_dist_mes | val_dist_mes_nuevas | val_dist_acum  |
|-------|----|--------------|---------------------|----------------|
|  1996 |  2 |            3 |                   3 |             3  |
|  1996 |  3 |            4 |                   3 |             6  |
|  1996 |  4 |            4 |                   4 |             10 |
|  1997 |  3 |            4 |                   4 |             4  |
|  1997 |  4 |            4 |                   1 |             5  |
```

Comment: Im expecting something like this

Comment: year | mn | val_dist_mes | val_dist_mes_nuevas | val_dist_acum |
   ------ |------|-------------------|-------------------------------|---------------------|
  1996 |  2   |            3         |                   3                |             3          |
  1996 |  3   |            4         |                   3                |             6          |
  1996 |  4   |            4         |                   4                |            10         |
  1997 |  4   |            1         |                   1                |            1           |

Comment: the query seems to contain transact-sql specifics, you should remove irrelevant tags

Comment: The SAS tag doesn't appear to be relevant here either., if T-SQL perhaps more specific SQL tags are appropriate.

Comment: If it was SAS, I would suggest a data step for your cumulative counts using a retain statement. Running totals are never straightforward in SQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding `Year` in `group by` and `partition by` should fix the problem

```
SELECT AÑO, 
       mn, 
       Count(DISTINCT( valuacion1 ))             AS Val_Dist_Mes, 
       Sum(flag)                                 AS Val_Dist_Mes_Nuevas, 
       Sum(Sum(flag)) 
         OVER ( 
           partition BY AÑO 
           ORDER BY mn rows UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) AS Val_Dist_Acum 
FROM   (SELECT valuacion1, 
               Extract(month FROM fecha_captura) AS mn, 
               Extract(year FROM fecha_captura)  AS AÑO, 
               CASE -- find the first year when a customer placed an order 
                 WHEN Extract(month FROM fecha_captura) = Min ( 
                      Extract(month FROM fecha_captura)) 
                      OVER ( 
                        partition BY valuacion1, Extract(year 
                      FROM fecha_captura)) THEN 1 
                 ELSE 0 
               END                               AS flag 
        FROM   table2 
        GROUP  BY fecha_captura, 
                  valuacion1) AS dt 
GROUP  BY mn, 
          AÑO
```

- [**SQL FIDDLE DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/0e975/24)

Comment: Thanks VR46, I made the changes, Im struggling with the partition instruction perhaps you could help me too. Im expecting the count distinct on VALUACION1 to be counted for each year and to be reseted on the following year, it seems that if a value is found no matter the year its not counted after on the next year. Im expecting this result. For instance on Year 1996 Month 4 value 12352 is not being counted because it appears on Year 1997 Month 3. The same happens with Year 1997 Month 4 12345, its not being considered since it has been counted on Year 1996 Month 2.

Comment: I have edited the query with the modifications and the expected result above.

Comment: could you help me with this problem please?

Comment: @JSuarez - Sorry i forgot about this will help you now for sure :)